# How to run AG Grid modules locally?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to modify one of the AG Grid community modules. Therefore, I've forked the [AG Grid repository](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid).

Is there a way to serve the community modules locally with the watch mode?
Are there any unit and end-to-end tests I could run to check if my modification doesn't break other features?